# How can I enable/disable perl's edit-in-place feature?

Tags: perl

If I invoke perl with the `-i` flag, it will edit input files in place; `i.bak` will create a backup with the extension `.bak`. But this requires me to either put `#!/usr/bin/perl -i` in my script, or explicitly use `perl -i` on the command line.

I would like my script itself to control if/when this happens. Is there a way to programmatically activate this perl feature, e.g., by modifying perl's idea of how it was invoked, or by setting a special variable?

Two workarounds I already know about:

- I could invoke perl from the command line: `perl -i.bak ~/bin/myscript`. But I want to be able to just type `myscript`.
- I could implement in-place editing from scratch. If there's no way to trigger the built-in version, this is what I'll probably do.

Comment: You want the program you are creating to decide when the files should be edited in place, and *not* the user? That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Well, actually I'm going to control it with commandline options :-)

Comment: So let me get this straight... you want to avoid using command line options, so that you can use your own command line options....? That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @TLP, try handling the command line options of a script that you run by typing `myscript`, and you'll understand.

Comment: Another way to put it: If there was a way to pass a commandline option from my script to the running perl interpreter, it would solve my problem.

Comment: Generally speaking, I think that the in-place edit should be used sparingly, and only as a shortcut. If you always print to standard output, you can simply redirect output where you want it, e.g. `myscript foo.txt > bar.txt`

Comment: @TLP Generally speaking, I agree. That's why I wanted to control it, instead of putting `#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak` in the script.

Comment: Sometimes people think just because a backup is made, their data is safe, but `-i.bak` is really just as much of a loaded gun as `-i` is, when it comes to shooting yourself in the foot. Running the script twice, for example, overwrites your backup. Writing your own backup handler would be preferable, especially if you have novice users that will be using your program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the `$^I` variable in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar#%24INPLACE_EDIT).

Comment: I've tried experimenting with this a bit, and trying to toggle in-place editing during runtime gives some... interesting results.

Comment: @ysth Yes. It works if I activate it after the first read, but not the other way around, disable it after the first read. Then it continues to print to the first file with the content from the second.

Comment: @TLP, that's good to know. Sounds like a straight-up bug, even if it's simply a consequence of the implementation. I'm just enabling the flag before any file i/o, which must be the use case it was designed for; I haven't noticed any weirdness yet.

Comment: @TLP: I would only expect it to have any effect at the moment a new file is opened (implicitly by readline ARGV) and that sounds consistent with what you are saying

Comment: @ysth, If you start an in-place edit with file 1, then turn off `$^I`, and go on to file 2, I would expect either (a) file 2 goes to stdout as intended, or (b) file 2 is edited in place (change to `$^I` is ignored). Appending file 2 to file 1 is a consequence of the implementation: _no $^I = assume stdout = assume no need to redirect output._ These assumptions are wrong.